# Facebook Custom Button Implementation Issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[connect.js](http://pastebin.com/nTaFjArL)

[connect.php](http://pastebin.com/19AVWGuE)

I am trying to create Facebook Login Custom Button Using Facebook SDK. I have created it successfully and able to login successfully via clicking on "Continue With facebook" button . But the problem is whenever I redirects to memberpage after clicking on continue with facebook button and tries to click on "Logout" button which is on memberpage to kill the session created by custom button . It redirects me to the sigin page. But within seconds it again redirect me to the memberpage. So the issue is here : I am redirecting to the memberpage again and again and not able to logout.However, If i try login without facebook using provided Username and password . I am able to login and logout without any issue. Above I have given the links for my code.

connect.js(Contains facebook login and authentication code.)

```
  function getUserDetails() {
        FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday,gender,first_name,last_name,verified,hometown', function(response) {

                var data = {
                    access_token: FB.getAccessToken(),
                    fb_id: response.id,
                    email: response.email,
                    name: response.name,
                    first_name: response.first_name,
                    last_name: response.last_name,
                    birthday:response.birthday,
                    verified: response.verified,
                    hometown:response.hometown.name,
                    gender: response.gender
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url:'connect.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                     data:  {user:data}
                });


        });

    }


    function statusChangeCallback(response)
    {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            $("div.fb-login").hide();
            getUserDetails();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
            url:'connect.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    action: 'logout.php'
                }
            });
           }
    }

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
        {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }
        FB.login(function(response){
           checkLoginState();
         },{scope: 'public_profile,email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_hometown'}); 

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxxxx',
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : false,
            version    : 'v2.6',
            status     : true, // check login status
            oauth      : true // enable OAuth 2.0

        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Connect.php(The data sending via connect.js goes here and by some methods it gets stored in database and used to create session variables.)

logout.php:(whenever user click on logout button given on memberpage.php it redirects user to this page and then after destroying sessions it redirects user to sigin page.)

```
$session_destroy();
```

signin.php:

```
<script src="connect.js"></script>

<button onclick="FB.login()">Continue With Facebook</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

Here is a "FB.init" function which calls everytime automatically when the page is loaded or refreshed . It has a function "FB.getLoginStatus" which was pretending to destroy the session because it was invoking again and again and new session was creating. On basis of which signin page checking for the session variables and getting session variables value even after destroying the session using logouy which was making the signin page to redirect to member page.
But now I removed the FB.getLoginStatus function from FB.init and now the site is working fine.